# TOwnedCollection and using multiple inherited TCollectionItem

Tags: delphi, collections, tcollection

I'm having problems adding my own `TCollectionItem` classes (inherited from `TCollectionItem`) within the same `TOwnedCollection`.

I referred to Indy's `IdMessageParts.pas` for `TIdMessagePart` as recommended.  So I must be missing something as I get a "Invalid class type" error when adding `TMyItem2`.

I would like `MyItems: TOwnedCollection` to be able to store `TMyItem`, `TMyItem2`, `TMyItem3`.  But I get an "Invalid typecast" error when adding `TMyItem2` and `TMyItem3` (only `TMyItem` can be accepted).

Did I miss something?

```
TMyItem = class(TCollectionItem)
private
  FLabelName: string;
public
  constructor Create(Collection: TCollection); override;
  destructor Destroy; override;
published
  property LabelName: string read FLabelName write FLabelName;
end;

TMyItem2 = class(TMyItem)
private
  FCaption: string;
published
  property Caption: string read FCaption write FCaption;
end;

TMyItem3 = class(TMyItem)
private
  FCaption3: string;
published
  property Caption3: string read FCaption3 write FCaption3;
end;

TMyItems = class(TOwnedCollection)
private
  function GetMyItem(aIndex: Integer): TMyItem;
protected
  constructor Create(aOwner: TAsapListview);
  function GetOwner: TPersistent; override;
public
  function Add: TMyItem;
  function IndexOf(aFieldName: string): Integer;
  function MyItemByFieldName(aFieldName: string): TMyItem;
  property Items[aIndex: Integer]: TMyItem read GetMyItem; default;
end;

// NOTE: in idMessageParts.pas the add is defined this way
// which I don't quite understand
{
function TIdMessageParts.Add: TIdMessagePart;
begin
  // This helps prevent TIdMessagePart from being added
  Result := nil;
end;
}

// this is the calling code
with MyItems.Add do
begin
  LabelName := 'test';  // works
end;
// Error of invalid typecast occurred here
with MyItems.Add as TMyItem2 do  // typecast error here
begin
  LabelName := 'label item2';
  Caption := 'caption item2';
end;
with MyItems.Add as TMyItem3 do  // typecast error here
begin
  LabelName := 'label item2';
  Caption := 'caption item2';
  Caption3 := 'caption3 item2';
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inherited `TCollection.Add()` method creates an instance of the class type that is specified in the `TCollection` constructor. So `Add()` is useless when dealing with multiple `TCollectionItem`-derived classes, since you can't add multiple classes that way.

This code:

```
with MyItems.Add do
begin
 ...
end;
```

Works because you told `TMyItems` that its item class type is `TMyItem`, so that is what `Add()` creates.

This code:

```
with MyItems.Add as TMyItem2 do
...
with MyItems.Add as TMyItem3 do
```

Fails for the same reason. You told `TMyItems` to create `TMyItem` objects, so you can't cast them to your other class types.

Indy's `TIdMessageParts` collection overrides `Add()` to dissuade users from using `Add()` in this manner.

To accomplish what you want (and what Indy does), you need to call the `TCollectionItem` constructor instead of using `Add()`, eg:

```
with TMyItem.Create(MyItems) do
begin
  LabelName := 'test';  // works
end;

with TMyItem2.Create(MyItems) do
begin
  LabelName := 'label item2';
  Caption := 'caption item2';
end;

with TMyItem3.Create(MyItems) do
begin
  LabelName := 'label item2';
  Caption := 'caption item2';
  Caption3 := 'caption3 item2';
end;
```

Comment: I saw the light. I didn't know TCollectionItem can be created this way. Much appreciated for the sample code and the precise clarification!

Comment: However, if I save the component to a stream and restore it, it gives a Caption / Caption3  error : 
Error reading TMyComponent.MyItems: Error reading TMyItem.Caption3: Property does not exist.

Comment: @PeterJones correct, because the native DFM streaming system only knows how to stream a `TCollection` using its constructor-specified item class, not multiple derived classes. When a `TCollection` is written to a DFM stream, all of the item properties are written as expected, since they are known to RTTI. But when reading a `TCollection` from a DFM stream, `TCollection.Add()` is called for each item, and the stored properties are read into each item. That is why you are getting an error about a derived class property not existing in a base class.

Comment: @PeterJones If you want to store multiple derived class items in a stream, you will have to manually write/read the `TCollection` to/from the stream, not using the native DFM streaming. That way, you can write each item's `ClassName` to the stream so you can read it back out and know which derived class to create for each item. Indy's `TIdMessageParts` collection doesn't go that far, because its items are never created at design-time, only at runtime, and thus are never streamed.

Comment: thanks for the pointer. Looks like a very involved process.  Just surprised no Delphi component made use of this feature.  I wish Delphi streaming will take care of it since it allows multiple derived class items.

Comment: @PeterJones using multiple derived classes in a `TCollection` is actually quite rare, which is why the native DFM system was never setup to handle it. It would take only a few lines of code in the RTL for Embarcadero to implement this natively, but they haven't done that yet.

Comment: Is it safe to say that Collections and CollectionItems are not meant to be used with multiple derived classes? I moved to TPersistent, and using an ObjectList - because im not going to create these items at designtime (for now).

Comment: @eXXecutor **Using** multiple derived item classes is fine. **Streaming** them is not (easily). But, if you are not using these classes at design-time, or in streams at runtime, then this issue is moot.